# http (json) library, client and server, possibly asynchronous

Tags: java, json, http

I have to write a little Java program that stands in the middle of a client and the true http server. I glanced over Apache's HttpAsyncClient, but it's in fact a client library. Is there any other library capable of listening as server too?

If it helps, I need is to parse JSON in this program, but I don't think that it matters.

Comment: what do you actually want to acomplish, it isn't clear at all

Comment: well, what more do you want to know? You don't need extra particulars. I need a library capable of getting and making (multiple concurrent) http requests and responses with the smallest hassle as possible.

Comment: so you need an HTTP Proxy not a library? If so for what reason, that is important to answer the question, otherwise it will probably get closed.

Comment: no, I have to do some processing on this data, and there's no direct correlation between the number of connections and request between client-program and program-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at netty: http://netty.io/

Once has been part of jboss and is now a stand-alone project.